# PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed - jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, kubernetes

I am facing below error while doing the kubernetes deployment from jenkins.

```
ERROR: ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
```

**Objective :** How can I skip SSL certificate issue ?

Comment: Problem is with certificate file that you are using. Plz check it properly.

Comment: I want to skip the ssl part , how can i skip .

Comment: You may be able to use insecure-skip-tls-verify: true in the config to skip the check

Comment: insecure-skip-tls-verify: where we need to pass this.. can you please mention the path

Comment: Use a good certificate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this property given below in kubernetes `.yaml` configuration file.

```
insecure-skip-tls-verify: true
```

Comment: steps{ 
 
   kubernetesDeploy(
   configs: "Production/Deployment_scripts/NSR-deployment.yaml",
   kubeconfigId: 'kubernetes-config',
  // enableConfigSubstitusion: true
  )  i am passing through jenkinsfile to deploy my application on kubernetes cluster.

Comment: to skip the cert i have used plugin called skip-certificate-check. Still i am getting same error .. is there anyway to skip the ssl cert ?

Comment: it worked for me.. thank you so mcuh - insecure-skip-tls-verify: true